# How I can fix error firebaseAuthWebException app android?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

My app in unity (android ) show me this message error:

> "Java Class com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWebException not
>   found. Please verify the AAR which contains the
>   com/google/firebase/auth/firebaseAuthWebException class is included in
>   your app"

Answer (score 0):

Try re-importing (completely remove and import again) Firebase, I had this error before, don't really know why but re-importing worked for me.